# Python: creating a tuple with predetermined length

Tags: python, tuples

I'm working on a Python problem where I need to set up a tuple with a pre-defined length `n` (being `n` an input of the program), where each element must have a specific float value (e.g. `H`), similar to what is possible to do with NumPy arrays in this way:

```
import numpy as np

arr = H*np.ones(n)
```

Is it possible for a tuple?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create one with a generator expression:

```
tuple(H for _ in range(n))
```

Instead of a constant value `H` you can fill the tuple with an arbitrary expression depending on the iteration variable (which was not used above and therefore named `_` by convention):

```
tuple(f(i) for i in range(n))
```

For example, to fill the first half with `G` and the second half with `H`, you can use a conditional expression as `f(i)`:

```
tuple(G if i < n/2 else H for i in range(n))
```